# Is there a word to refer to the cap some British soldiers wear?

Tags: single-word-requests

Whenever Britain is abuzz with some celebration, I find these people (cops or soldiers?) in red strutting about in parades wearing an elongated black headdress. 
[image: Royal parade]

Is there a word for this peculiar hat, just like there is a *zuchetto* to refer to the Pope's cap?

Comment: +1, but *zucchetto* is only one of the Pope's caps; so you should edit your question as follow "...a zuchetto to refer to one of the Pope's caps?".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called a [bearskin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearskin), and as the wikipedia link shows it is not limited to British soldiers.

Comment: Is a zucchetto Catholic? Does a bearskin crap in the woods?

Comment: @JeffSahol I think the question is, if a bearskin does crap in the woods, does anyone hear it?

Answer (score 0):

NominSim is right. Also, the people that wear them are soldiers. It is part of the ceremonial uniform of the guards regiments.

They are literally, made of bear skin.